# How to change class to currently hovered cells in html tables

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I tried to change class with hovering, I can see class change from`1` to `hovering cells`

But I would like to change class from`1` to `currently hovered cells`

if mouse move `1` to `10` to `2` ,then `currently hovered cells`=`2` therefore only `1`and`2` will be changed.

But now in such case,class of `1`to`10`is changed.

Are there any way to realize it?

Thanks

```js
$("td").hover(function() {
    const id = Number($(this).attr('id'));
    
    for(var j = 1;j <= id; j++){
      $("#"+j).addClass("aqua");
    }
  });
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 10px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
  <td id="11">11</td>
  <td id="12">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question isn't that clear, but it seems like it's doing what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to remove classes. Then add again.

```js
$("td").hover(function() {
    const id = Number($(this).attr('id'));
    $("table td").removeClass("aqua");
    for(var j = 1;j <= id; j++){
      $("#"+j).addClass("aqua");
    }
  });
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 10px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
  <td id="11">11</td>
  <td id="12">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```